# Magento2 Payment Methods Not Showing at Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

Using latest version 2.1.6 of Magento2. Payment methods are enabled in admin but not showing on our checkout page. They are showing fine when we manually process an order from the sales > orders area of Magento dashboard. Shipping methods show fine. All they obvious settings are in place and cache cleared etc. Any ideas where to start on establishing why this issue occurs?

First line of system.log file entry I think is related is below:

> [2017-05-11 13:06:07] main.INFO: Item Magento_Backend::system_currency
>   was removed [] []

But the currency is set as it should be in Magento settings.

Comment: Is there any browser error console?

Comment: Negative sorry, although have clocked what I think is relevant to the issue in the system.log file so uploading that to this thread in main question above in hope somebody knows what is wrong from that. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there are some conditions for your payment? Maybe it can be used for certain address or shipping method combination?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the currency is set in your Store View, and apply the changes. Then check out in incognito mode.

Comment: Currency is set. It was already set before deciphering this payment methods not showing issue. Created when the Magento store was made. And then re-saved today to be sure. When you say checkout in incognito mode, is that purely for purpose of fresh browser being used?

Comment: Yes, it's to be sure that the content is not cached in the browser.

Comment: Also try to recompile DI and refresh static content.

Comment: I have recompiled already and cleared all caches from admin and from var folder. My refresh static content, do you mean redeploy?